# Does system identification of a drive as "Fixed Hard Disk" mean that it is not an SSD?

Tags: ssd, hp-laptop

I had recently bought a laptop. Among the chief reason why I was compelled to buy it was the fact that "it had a 128 GB SSD".

Upon inspection, I can't seem to directly confirm it. I tried three different ways to arrive at the disk media type, but it all said the same thing: Fixed hard disk.

Does this mean that the laptop actually contains a hard drive rather than an SSD?

Comment: "Fixed" differentiates an internal drive from a removable (e.g., USB) drive.  SSDs are designed to mimic a hard drive so that they are plug and play on a hard drive interface.  The fact that the system identified it as a "hard drive" doesn't mean a hard drive was installed.  It just means the system sees it and is treating it as it would a hard drive.  To verify the actual hardware, you can look at it if it is in an accessible compartment, or as John describes, find it's identifier and look it up.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question:

You can check the media type of a drive by going to *Defragment and Optimize your devices*

I had just learned about it now. Regards to those who contributed.

Comment: That mis-identifies one of my SSDs. I wouldn't trust that.

Comment: @fixer1234: It's fine to use it on an SSD, because it actually performs SSD-specific tasks when it detects an SSD. (For HDDs it'll perform defragmentation, for SSDs and "thin-provisioned" volumes it'll send TRIM or other apropriate discard command.)